# MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri) returning null

Tags: android, bitmap

Facing issue please help, thanks

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri)
```

returns null for some images  while using in Fragment. Is it because of image size?

Comment: ContentResolver#query? could you please explain little??

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5312012 byte allocation with 4030456 free bytes and 3MB until OOM

Comment: Resizing the image solved my issue...Thank you